# primary key in sql server uneditable in mapinfo attribute?

Tags: mapinfo, sql-server

I trying create table relationship in sqlserver 2008 R2. Tables will have spatial table and non-spatial (tabular) .  I having trouble while selecting varchar field as primary key, this field cannon be editted on mapinfo attribute while I create new shape.
I tried use MI_PRINX as primary key but still success to get primary key field editable in mapinfo attribute editing.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use a numeric (integer) column as your primary key?